# PyTorch out of GPU memory after 1 epoch

Tags: python, pytorch

I trained model but after 1 epoch, CUDA error occured.
I changed train batch size to 1 and add torch.cuda.empty_cache() but nothing changed.
How should I change?

```
Warming up dataloader
using pin_memory on device 0
Num per train_loader 562
Num per valid_loader 241
  0%|          | 0/201 [00:00<?, ?it/s][21:03:49.396] train Epoch: 0 loss: 1.122958 dice: 0.047626 
[21:03:49.397] train Epoch: 0 loss: 1.078192 dice: 0.039761 
[21:04:32.062] val Epoch: 0 loss: 1.148290 dice: 0.054719 
[21:04:32.062] val Epoch: 0 loss: 1.079843 dice: 0.040041 
[21:04:32.062] Time till now 0h 25m 5s
[21:04:32.062] Time: 2022-01-03 21:04:32.062486
  0%|          | 1/201 [05:24<18:01:12, 324.36s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Goeun/PycharmProjects/SP_guided_Noisy_Label_Seg/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    nlss_seg.noise_aware_training()
  File "C:\Users\Goeun\PycharmProjects\SP_guided_Noisy_Label_Seg\lib\nlss.py", line 513, in noise_aware_training
    preds_sm = self.super_pixel_smoothing(preds, superpixels)
  File "C:\Users\Goeun\PycharmProjects\SP_guided_Noisy_Label_Seg\lib\nlss.py", line 944, in super_pixel_smoothing
    smooth_value = pixel_map_onehot.sum(dim=(0, 1)) / ((onehot_mask == 1).sum(dim=(0, 1)) + eps)  # (K)
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 196.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 6.46 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 6.55 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: have  you tried to use the num of workers as one&

Comment: I'm using 2070 super gpu.

Comment: I use 1 of workers. The error occurs in 'pixel_map_fla = pixel_map_.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, K)'

Comment: what is size of your model ? try to use something like `torchinfo.summary` and see how heavy your model is

Comment: I got it. That operation causes big matrix. So my computer can't afford it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible causes :

1. (Most likely) you forget to use detach() after backpropagating the loss with loss.backward()

> loss.backward() ------->
> loss.detach()

2. You have a problem with you CUDA or your computer is using GPU for another task